# "before each" hook: workFn error

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am running my tests with karma and phantom, Also I'm using mocha and sinon and tests are getting failed with below error:

```
EditResourceCategoryDialogTest EditResourceCategoryDialogController "before each" hook: workFn
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=resourceofferingsApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20
```

Sample code:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var assert = require('chai').assert;
    var sinon = require('sinon');
    var angular = require('angular');
    var angularMocks = require('angular.mocks');

    require('resourceofferings/app');
    require('dialog path');

    describe('EditResourceCategoryDialogTest', function () {

        beforeEach(module('resourceofferingsApp'));

        describe('EditResourceCategoryDialogController', function () {
            var $scope, ctrl;

            //you need to inject dependencies first
            beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $injector) {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            }));

            it('initialization test (create mode)', inject(function ($controller) {

                ctrl = $controller("EditResourceCategoryDialogController", {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    $uibModalInstance: null,
                    options: {
                        isEditMode: false
                    }
                });

                assert.equal($scope.isEditMode, false);
            }));

        });
    });
});
```

Its exactly getting failed here:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $injector) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));
```

Please help me to fix this issue..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
describe('controllers', function(){
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); // this is what you missed out
        controller = $controller('EditResourceCategoryDialogController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $uibModalInstance: null,
            options: {
                isEditMode: false
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Update: According to Angular ...

> A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten
>   to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't
>   be loaded.

Are you sure all needed files are loaded?

Comment: Thanks Smith. But still I'm getting same error:  "before each" hook: workFn